# Python metaclass base class params not initialising

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror, metaclass

I'm trying to create a metaclass that can extend the mandatory params from its base class.

I have the following base class:

```
class BaseClass(JSONEncoder):
    def __init__(self, field1, field2, ...):
        self.field1 = field1
        self.field2 = field2
        ...
```

There are about 10 params in total.

I am then creating a `dict` object that contains all of the params and values to satisfy the BaseClass, and create my metaclass using:

```
# getMandatoryFields returns {'field1': 'value1', 'field2': 'value2, ...}
mandatory_fields = self.getMandatoryFields(my_data)
ChildClass = type('ChildClass', (BaseClass,), mandatory_fields)
```

However, before I even try to extend the dict, I am getting an error that all the required positional args from the BaseClass are missing:

```
TypeError: __init__() missing 10 required positional arguments: 'field1', 'field2',...
```

I am think this is to do with dict unpacking, but I cannot seem to get these values to be found.  I assume that because I can pass in a class for inheritance to the `type` constructor that this is possible, but I cannot seem to find the answer.

Comment: "However, before I even try to extend the dict, I am getting an error that all the required positional args from the BaseClass are missing" what does this mean? Why don't you provide a [mcve]. Your question is unclear. You mention meta classes, for example, but there are no meta classes in your code. It sounds like you tried to instantiate `ChildClass` without any arguments, but where or why that is happening isn't clear

Comment: "I am then creating a dict object that contains all of the params and values to satisfy the BaseClass, and create my metaclass using:" That is *not* what the code you show there is doing. That code creates a *regular class* with class attributes. The way your `__init__` is defined still requires those arguments. I think there is some fundamental misunderstanding of what `type` is doing here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Can you help with my understanding?  My source material was https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/#example-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your code does is to create a new class which *has* the default values you want as class attributes - alright. But it doesn't touch the `__init__` function itself: it still requires 10 parameters - it won't know to pull default values from the class attributes.

You have to perceive that while it is common practice to receive parameters in a class' `__init__` method and set instance attributes with that same names, that is just done in plain code: nothing(*) in the language itself links class (or instance) attribute names with the parameter names in `__init__`.

(*) Well, "nothing" in the core language - although it is such a common practice, that late in the game Python threw in the dataclasses module which does exactly that: assume that you want an `__init__` whose attributes mirror the ones declared in the class and auto-generate that.

If the `__init__` method on your base class does just that, and call no other code, do not operate on the arguments received, no nothing, you can just use dataclasses in your problem - the dynamic class generated by calling `type`  will just override the defaults:

```
In [18]: @dataclasses.dataclass
    ...: class Base:
    ...:     field1: str = ""
    ...:     field2: int = 0
    ...: 

In [19]: new_class = type("new_class", (Base,), {"field1": "foobar", "field2": 42})

In [20]: instance = new_class()

In [21]: instance
Out[21]: new_class(field1='', field2=0)
```

Perceive that you don't write an `__init__` in the base class: dataclasses will generate one for you. If you have some base code to exectue in `__init__`, dataclasses support a `__post_init__` method, which receives only `self` as an argument, and is called after the instance attributes are set: right your needed code in there.

(beware that this approach might not be compatible with more advanced use of dataclasses, such as using `dataclasses.field` to create smarter default values in the base body)

If for some reason you can't use dataclasses (the base class is not under your control or it performs some calculations on the received arguments), then you will need to create a decorated version of that `__init__` in the class you create.

The idea would be to build a decorator that will inspect the `__init__` signature for parameter names, and try to extract those from the class attributes, if they were not passed in as `**kwargs`,  before calling the original `__init__`. I think that dataclasses will just work in your case, though.

Comment: Thank you very much for such an in-depth explanation and solution.  I'm fairly new to Python so this is great knowledge and understanding.  Using the `dataclass` annotation worked in my case.

Comment: Great. Being "new" does not mean you won't bring great insights. If you check the other questions tagged "metaclass", they are almost entirely about _custom_ metaclasses, for example. While yours is just about _using_ the default metaclass (`type`) - it is correctly tagged, and just let me wondering why no one else tags questions related with `type` with `metaclass`.